# Prevent volume rocker from disabling silent mode

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, volume-control, silent-mode

On my Galaxy S2 Skyrocket, everytime I bump the volume rocker the phone comes out of silent mode. I hate this. The only way I want my phone going into or coming out of silent mode with a hard button is by holding the power until the modal shows up. Is there any way to prevent the volume rocker from knocking the sound back on when in silent mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some apps that will do this for you:

RingGuard: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.x475aws.android.ringguard&hl=en
Volume Locker: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.hourdb.volumelocker&feature=related_apps

Comment: Volume Locker did the trick, but other frustrations with Android pushed me onto WP8.